# View background color doesn't apply the Opacity after it loads automatically in IOS

Tags: ios, view, background, opacity

I am setting the view background in the attribute with opacity but when the screen loads in show segue , it is momentarily showing the light blue color with opacity but than makes it dark color totally opaque;
I tried even by changing the unchecking the opaque attribute nothing works.

Comment: You are looking for alpha property may be?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on iOS 7 and found three solutions:

- add your controller programmatically with `-addSubview` and `-addChildViewController` (not usefull if you have navigation bar for example, because it will cover you new screen)
- make a screenshot and set it as backgroundColor when animation will complete (easy, but it's a 'kludge')
- create a new UIWindow for transparent controller (more complicated but very usefull)